# Regular concat with non regular

Tags: regular-languages

If L is regular and M is non regular; then L.M is necessarily not regular. Is this true or false? And why?

I feel its false

Comment: It's false. Whenever you need to prove that some weird combination of languages could be regular, it usualy helps to remember that the empty language, any finite language and $\Sigma^*$ are all regular (not all of these facts are useful in this particular case) and that you can usually "attack" the combining operation by making it trivial (e.g., regular intersect non-regular can be regular because $\emptyset\cap\text{anything}=\emptyset$, and $\text{finite}\cap\text{anything}$ is finite).

Comment: Yup....i thought the exact same way....thank you :)

Comment: What have you done to try to answer the question on your own?  Have you tried some examples?  Have you checked the closure properties of regular languages?  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own before asking here.

Comment: Yep i did try out a few examples before i posted it here....i tried one with sigma^kleene star (using a cell phone sorry) and a^nb^n ....i was using this platform to confirm my findings

Answer (score 5):

The claim is this:

> If $L$ is a regular language and $M$ is a non-regular language, then the concatenation $LM$ of the two languages is necessarily non-regular.

If this claim is false, all you need to do is to provide one counterexample showing that it's false. If the claim is true, you need to prove that it's true for any languages $L$ and $M$, a much harder task. Fortunately, this claim is not true.

If we let $L = \emptyset$ and let $M$ be any non-regular language, then $LM = \emptyset = L$, a regular language.

Now, if that feels too much like cheating, we can find other examples. Consider this:

1. $L = \Sigma^*$
2. $M = \{ww^R \mid w \in \Sigma^*\}$

$L$ is regular, $M$ is non-regular (in fact, it's the language of palindromes, a canonical context-free language). Since the empty word is in $M$, we have $LM = \Sigma^* = L$, so the concatenation is regular.